# iOS build not showing up for testflight beta testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I am building the IPA (via fastlane with a distribution profile). The entitlements show `beta-reports-active=1`:

[image: entitlements]

Upload with the AppLoader is successful - but it's not showing up for testing:

[image: no test build]

The build shows up under "Activity" though - but showing "Missing Beta Entitlements"

[image: build list]

Looking into the build details on iTunes Connect the entitlements seem to be really missing the beta entitlements:

[image: iTunes Connect entitlements]

Anyone a clue what I am missing?

Comment: Try to create new Provisioning Profile and reupload?

Comment: But why? it was just recently generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `fastlane` `gym` (in my case) creating an IPA that was invalid. I ditched it and are now building through `xcodebuild` without problems.

Both `Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision` and `codesign -d --entitlements :- Payload/*.app` need to have `beta-reports-active = 1` set. 
That wasn't always the case with `gym`. See the [github issue explaining the details](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/4907#issuecomment-224893544)

Without `use_legacy_build_api: true` [`gym` also has trouble picking the right provisioning profile](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/5066).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, although I think it's the exact same one.

When uploading an app using Pilot or Application Loader, I was able to select the app for external testing, but not for internal testing.

## Solution

Use an adhoc distribution provisioning profile.

I've created the following lane to publish an app for internal testing:

```
lane :internal do |options|
  unlock_keychain(path: 'login')
  cert(
    username: options[:username],
    output_path: './fastlane/certs'
  )
  provisioning_profile = sigh(
    username: options[:username],
    adhoc: true
  )
  FileUtils.mkdir_p('www')
  sh("cordova build ios --release --device -- --provisioningProfile=#{provisioning_profile}")
  pilot(
    username: options[:username],
    distribute_external: false,
    ipa: 'platforms/ios/build/device/<app_name>.ipa'
  )
end
```

**Note**: Pilot raised an error, but I was still able to select the app for internal testing in iTunes Connect manually.